# Want to select all values but only selecting one

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I am selecting many values from database but there is a row where I can only select one.

[image: here]

`Equipamento` row has many values but when I open a pop up on click `ver mais` and it only shows one value

[image: here]

`tipo` row (tipo = equipamento I have to change that title)

JS:

```
var idocorrencia;
$(document).on("click","#listagem tr td button", 
    function(e) {
        idocorrencia = $(this).parent().attr("idlista");
        $("#listagem caption").text($(this).text());
        console.log(idocorrencia);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../php/temp.php',
            data: { idoc : idocorrencia },
            success: function(data) {
                var data_array = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("#descricao").empty().append( data_array['descricao'] );
                $("#qtd").empty().append( data_array['qtd'] );
                $("#sala").empty().append( data_array['sala'] );
                $("#tipo").empty().append( data_array['tipo'] );
                $("#data").empty().append( data_array['data'] );
                $("#hora").empty().append( data_array['hora'] );
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Here is the php code:

```
$dados = array();
if(isset($_POST["idoc"])) {
    $idoc = $_POST["idoc"];
    $sql = "SELECT m.tipo FROM `material` as m INNER JOIN `ocorrencia_detalhe` 
        as od on m.id = od.id_tipo AND od.id_ocorrencia=$idoc";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $tipo = $r['tipo'];
    }

    $dados["tipo"] = $tipo;
    echo json_encode($dados);
```

And then it displays like this:

```
<div id="sala"></div>
<textarea id="descricao"></textarea>
<div id="data"></div>
<div id="hora"></div>
<div id="tipo"></div>
<p id="qtd"></p>
```

Comment: You keep overwriting `$tipo`. Make it an array and append to it instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. You keep overwriting your `$tipo` variable for each iteration. Append it to an array instead.
2. You are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - use a prepared statement with placeholders instead.

```php
$dados = array();
if (isset($_POST["idoc"])) {
    $idoc = $_POST["idoc"];
    $sql = "SELECT m.tipo 
            FROM `material` as m 
            INNER JOIN `ocorrencia_detalhe` as od 
              ON m.id = od.id_tipo
            WHERE od.id_ocorrencia=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $idoc);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($tipo);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
         $dados['tipo'][] = $tipo;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    echo json_encode($dados);
}
```

Also, see how much easier this code is to read? Properly indented and formatted code is much better to troubleshoot, and for others to read.